# Can we find validity proofs by means of rules of inference with FindEquationalProof?

Tags: logic, theorem-proving

Can we find proofs such as:

> [image]

Using [FindEquationalProof](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindEquationalProof.html)? My guess is "yes" but I don't know what would be the "axioms" here nor how would we write this in Mathematica.

Comment: Please take a look at [Implementation of Common Axiom Systems and Proof Generation](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1382544).

Comment: I would do something like this as per the documentation https://pastebin.com/SYUQFEcZ. Unfortunately, I've had it running for 20 mins and it still hasn't finished running.

Comment: What axioms do you want?

Comment: @ShyPerson The rules of inference. I want it to apply rules of inference, don't know if this is possible though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go.
The definition of Boolean Logic comes directly from the documentation of FindEquationalProof:

```
booleanLogic = 
 {ForAll[{a, b}, and[a, b] == and[b, a]], 
  ForAll[{a, b}, or[a, b] == or[b, a]], 
  ForAll[{a, b}, and[a, or[b, not[b]]] == a], 
  ForAll[{a, b}, or[a, and[b, not[b]]] == a], 
  ForAll[{a, b, c}, and[a, or[b, c]] == or[and[a, b], and[a, c]]], 
  ForAll[{a, b, c}, or[a, and[b, c]] == and[or[a, b], or[a, c]]]}
implicationDefinition = {ForAll[{a, b}, implies[a, b] == or[not[a], b]]}
premises = {implies[not[a], and[c, d]], implies[a, b], not[b]}
FindEquationalProof[c, Union[booleanLogic, implicationDefinition, premises]]
```

As to the original question of whether [traditional rules of inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_rules_of_inference#Rules_for_propositional_calculus) can be used in this part of Mathematica, the answer is no, because these are not equational theories, while the prover behind `FindEquationalProof` is an equational prover. More specifically, while the traditional inference rules are perfectly sound in the usual forward direction, a number of them are not correct in the reverse direction. For example, modus ponens is correct in the forward direction, but definitely not in the reverse direction. To be used in an equational prover, the rules have to be biconditional in order to be equations. So if you look at the Boolean logic axioms in my original solution, you will see they are all biconditional.

Comment: This is really nice! Can we make something that uses only rules of inference? I guess the proofs would be shorter.

Comment: @RedBanana: Glad you liked it. Please give a link to the rules of inference you want, and I'll see what I can do. Remember, the prover in Mathematica is just an equational prover, so everything has to be specified. It doesn't know the rules of inference innately.

Comment: @RedBanana: Or did you just want me to do an ad hoc version where I use the rules of inference in your example? The other thing to bear in mind is that the proofs generated by an equational prover probably can't be expected to look as nice or as short as those in a natural deduction proof.

Comment: I want to see if it's possible to make it prove that with the following [rules of inference for propositional calculus.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_rules_of_inference#Rules_for_propositional_calculus) Do you think it's possible?

Comment: @RedBanana: I've updated the answer to address this.

Comment: This is really interesting, I know next to nothing about logic. I just finished a "baby logic" course and wanted to try Mathematica theorem proving for fun. I got curious about the following: Can we prove the same with both equational proofs and rules of inference?

Comment: @RedBanana: Glad to hear of your interest in logic. I find it never gets old. As for your question, the rules of inference you cited are only for propositional logic, while equational proofs are a subset of [first order logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic), which is more powerful. So you can prove more in equational logic.

Comment: This is really interesting, are there other kinds of theorem provers that use something other than equational proofs? I am currently reading the following [book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-87882-5) and learning a bit about Isabelle/HOL along with it but I'm still at the very beginning.

Comment: @RedBanana: First, have a look at this [excellent Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_theorem_proving). Here
is one of the best [textbooks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:BookSources/9780079112514).
Also have a look at [SAT Solvers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAT_solver), which from a historical point of view have been a spectacular success. There is actually a SAT solver tucked into Mathematica under [SatisfiableQ](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SatisfiableQ.html).

Comment: This is really nice, thanks!